# Pandas: wrong merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
ID  qsex    age ranges  month   region  RuCitySize  counts
00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d    Женский 25-34   2016-02 Москва  Москва  1
00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d    Женский 25-34   2016-03 Москва  Москва  1
00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d    Женский 25-34   2016-04 Москва  Москва  1
00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d    Женский 25-34   2016-05 Москва  Москва  1
0035f7bb84690f3a7454edbaf5ece268    Женский 25-34   2016-02 Москва  Москва  1
00507d5d1772c03d2046144aeeca3593    Женский 25-34   2016-03 Москва  Москва  1
006ffdb5c45a47f087c2dc15ef39ebb3    Женский 25-34   2016-02 Москва  Москва  1
006ffdb5c45a47f087c2dc15ef39ebb3    Женский 25-34   2016-03 Москва  Москва  1
006ffdb5c45a47f087c2dc15ef39ebb3    Женский 25-34   2016-04 Москва  Москва  1
```

and another df

```
       qsex age ranges   RuCitySize   all
0   Женский      18-24      500-млн   117
1   Женский      18-24  Миллионники   271
2   Женский      18-24       Москва  1046
3   Женский      25-34      500-млн   150
4   Женский      25-34  Миллионники   368
5   Женский      25-34       Москва  2015
6   Женский      35-44      500-млн    59
```

I try to add column `all` to first df.
I use

```
res['inf'] = pd.merge(res, data, on=['qsex', 'age ranges', 'RuCitySize'], how='left')['all']
```

But it returns df with column `inf`, where all values are empty.
What I do wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, I'm getting a column filled with `2015` when using your code.

Comment: @Khris some values in the first df are not unique (ID and others). but month unique for every. But it return first, second and third line is equal to `2015`, but other s are None

Comment: Can you add the result you're getting to your post?

Comment: @Khris my data is more large, than that. I get `73          Москва       1   271.0  
86          Москва       1   129.0  
127        500-млн       1  1046.0  
128        500-млн       1  1046.0  
...            ...     ...     ...  
89023  Миллионники       1     NaN  
89024  Миллионники       1     NaN  
89029       Москва       1     NaN  
89030       Москва       1     NaN`

Comment: So you only get `NaN` further down in the dataframe? Then your `merge` isn't exactly doing what you want it to. Are you sure that `'left'` is the correct parameter for your `merge`? Have you read through the doc with its many examples? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @Khris I need to get 9 strings in `inf` with value 2015.

Comment: I see. But like I said, when testing your code I'm getting all nine strings with `2015`, none of them is empty, so to me everything looks correct.

Comment: @PetrPetrov - which version of python/pandas are you using? did you try using the latest version of pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html ?